# How to make multiple @Path in a @GET in JAX-RS API?

Tags: java, api, jax-rs

So, in my Resource class I have the following:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Carta> get() {
    return repositorio.getAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Carta getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return repositorio.getID(id);
}
```

both works, one is a general get (will get all) and the other get by ID. I need to add a third get by String but I'm failing with the @params. I need to add this to the Resource class:

```
@GET
@Path("{nome}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Carta> getNome(@PathParam("nome") String nome) {
    return repositorio.getString(nome);
}
```

if I comment the getById lines, my getByString works, the code is good, i just need to make both function at the same time, if it receives a number, it looks for an ID, if its a String it looks into name and description. Also, I wonder if it's better code practice to create more endpoints? Like /search/byid/xx and /search/byname/xxx instead of a general /search/xxx? Thanks.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to differentiate integer and string path params.

Something like 
`@Path("{id : \\d+}")` for integer.

You can read up more about URI precedence for JAX-RS [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-java-with/9781449361433/ch04.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than creating a different endpoint, you should enhance `List<Carta> get()` to support filtering by card name.

The expected way to do that is to use the `@QueryParam` annotation like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Carta> get(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    return repositorio.getCartas(name);
}
```

In the case of `null` name parameter, all `Carta` instances will be returned.

Comment: @nenchev please read the question more carefully. The getById endpoint is already implemented. My solution is about searching by name.